# NodeJS: Edit array of references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Suppose i have these models (dummy example):

```
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");
const DB = require("../db/db.config");

const buyerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    orders:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "order" }]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Buyer = DB.model("buyer", buyerSchema, "buyer");
module.exports = Buyer;
```

```
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");
const DB = require("../db/db.config");

const orderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    amount: {type: String},
    orderNumber:{type:Number}
    product:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "product" }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Order = DB.model("order", orderSchema, "order);
module.exports = Order;
```

I need to update the orders (one or many) from one specific buyer in the frontend.

Example: I want to change the amount in order X & Y from buyer A.

I know that i can just edit the order one by one it but i feel like there has to be a better way to do it. Is it possible to do it in one route / controller? If not, what is the best way to do it?

Any help are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give ref `buyerId` reference in order schema instead of `orders` reference in the buyer schema. it will be the right relation. and you can update orders through `buyerId` using mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` or `updateMany()`